# Horizontal and Vertical Center Divs with CSS, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a website using bootstrap, and I'm trying to make the content in the header centered vertically and horizontally. I'm so close, but for some reason there's something extra pushing on the left, making it not centered and adding a horizontal scroll bar. I can't seem to figure out what it is. Thanks for your help!

```css
.header {
  text-align: center;
  background: url(sunset-blue-darker.jpg) no-repeat center;
  height: 100vh;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}
.center-both-ways {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.intro-text {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-transform: none;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<header class="header" id="header">
  <!--header-start-->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="center-both-ways">
      <ul class="we-create animated fadeInUp delay-5s">
        <h1>HEADER</h1>
      </ul>
      <ul class="we-create animated fadeInUp delay-1s">
        <div class="col-xs-12 .col-sm-12 .col-lg-2 intro-text">
          <p>This is a
            <br>paragraph.</p>
        </div>
        <!-- end bootsrap div -->
      </ul>
      <!-- end transition effect -->
    </div>
    <!-- end center-both-ways -->
    <div class="arrow">
    </div>
    <!-- end arrow -->
  </div>
  <!-- close header -->
</header>
<!--header-end-->
```

Comment: .header { height: 100%;} That's "Y" axis, not sure about the "X", couldnt find what part is responsible.

Comment: You don't need to use the prefixes for background-size unless you are planning to serve very old browsers such as FF2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Why this is occuring

- The `.container` class has `padding-left: 15px` by default in bootstrap.
- Currently `.center-both-ways` is positioned relative to the viewport *but* there is no `left` property set on it, so it is being pushed 15px by its parent container's padding.

#### Simple fix

Set `left: 0` on `.center-both-ways` in order to attach it to the viewports edge and ignore its parents padding.

### Example

```css
.header {
  height: 100vh;
}
.center-both-ways {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<header class="header" id="header">
  <!--header-start-->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="center-both-ways">
      <ul class="we-create animated fadeInUp delay-5s">
        <h1>HEADER</h1>
      </ul>
      <ul class="we-create animated fadeInUp delay-1s">
        <div class="col-xs-12 .col-sm-12 .col-lg-2 intro-text">
          <p>This is a
            <br>paragraph.</p>
        </div>
        <!-- end bootsrap div -->
      </ul>
      <!-- end transition effect -->
    </div>
    <!-- end center-both-ways -->
    <div class="arrow">
    </div>
    <!-- end arrow -->
  </div>
  <!-- close header -->
</header>
<!--header-end-->
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution and explanation, this worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

For horizontal scroll bar.

```
.center-both-ways {
width: 99%;
}
```

For vertical

```
.header {
 height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Don't know if it's the most correct way to fix it, ( talking about 99%), but atleast you know which part is causing that.

Answer (score 0):

Your class `.center-both-ways` was creating that issue set it's left to 0 and it works fine. As below,

```
.center-both-ways {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  .......
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Let try to make `.container` display to table style, and change some code for `.center-both-ways`

see the code changed

```
.container {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:table;
}

.center-both-ways {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

i haven't test this code but it should be work :)